Movie about girl and man with a tent that led to another dimension
I watched this movie where a young woman/ teen girl was traveling with this old(ish) man. They had a big white tent thing that when you went into it it led you somewhere else (different dimension?). 
In the beginning they took this young man into it and it led to woods and I think there was a lion too. Then somehow the old man gets trapped in the tent and has to roam a desert for a really long time till he finally escapes. 
Then when he gets out he finds the young woman buts she's grown up and has fallen in love. And he decides she's better off without him. 
I think it was an American movie released in the early 2000s but it could have been late 90s. 

The part about the lion makes me think one of the Chronicles of Narnia movies which has Aslan - the god-like Lion and inter-dimensional travel via a wardrobe. There are also liberal uses of tents on the Narnia side and some desert scenes throughout the series.

Thank you for your answer. It wasn't any of the Chronicles of Narnia movies but I could see where you would relate the two.

So, my Mom found the movie for me. It was Dr. Parnassus' Imaginarium.
